# HTML5 CANVAS: How to save and reopen image from server

Tags: php, javascript, html, file, canvas

I draw something with html5-canvas. then i want to save it, and when the page is loaded again, I want to load the image I saved back to the canvas.  I succeed with saving the data into a file in the server, but for some reason it's a strange file that can't open by ant software, and ofcourse not by my canvas. I save it as png base64, but i tried other things that didn't work.

javascript code:

```
function save(){      //saves the canvas into a string as a base64 png image.   jsvalue is sent to the server by an html form
      var b_canvas = document.getElementById("a");
      var b_context = b_canvas.getContext("2d");
      var img = b_canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
      document.classic_form.jsvalue.value = img;

    }
```

---

```
            // opens the image file and displays it on the canvas
            var canvas = document.getElementById("a");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "backpicture.png";
    img.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
```

php code:

```
<?php
  $str=$_POST['jsvalue'];
  $file=fopen("backpicture.txt","w");
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      fwrite($file,$str);
  fclose($file) 
 ?>
```

it creates the file, but shows nothing on the canvas when I load the page again.
I also tried to use `Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG()`, but it still didn't work.

can you please help?
thanks!

Comment: Is the image hosted on the same domain as the Canvas? If not, that will throw a  SECURITY_ERR exception, because the origin-clean flag will be set to false.

Comment: Why do you have it as a text file in the php fopen?

Answer (score 3):

In order to save the file properly you need to decode the base64 data (and save as png):

```
file_put_contents('backpicture.png', base64_decode($str));
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Will give you something  like this:

> image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...[base64encoded_string]...

As @Variant said, you need to base64_decode it, but, ignoring "image/png;base64,"

This should work:

```
file_put_contents('backpicture.png',base64_decode(substr($str,22)));
```